# logstash geoip not working for IPv4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am indexing syslogs into elasticsearch using logstash[version 2.2],I am also using geoip to get the source and destination address but in certain logs the the geoip doesn't seem to work

```
**config file:** 

input {
        tcp {
                type => syslog
                port => 8001
        }
        udp {
                type => syslog
                port => 8001
        }


filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
         match => {
            "message" => "\<%{NUMBER:number}\>%{timestamp:timestamp} %{WORD:logType}: %{NUMBER:ruleNumber},%{NUMBER:subRuleNumber}%{DATA}%{NUMBER:tracker},%{WORD:realinterface},%{WORD:reasonForTheLogEntry},%{WORD:actionTakenThatResultedInTheLogEntry},%{WORD:directionOfTheTraffic},%{NUMBER:IPversion},%{DATA:class},%{DATA:flowLabel},%{NUMBER:hopLimit},%{WORD:protocol},%{NUMBER:protocolID},%{NUMBER:length},%{IPV6:srcIP},%{IPV6:destIP},%{NUMBER:srcPort},%{NUMBER:destPort},%{NUMBER:dataLength}"

                }
       add_field => { "event" => "name" }
     }

  }
geoip {
   source => "srcIP"
   target => "geoSrc"
 }
geoip {
   source => "destIP"
   target => "geoDest"
 }
geoip {
   source => "icmpDetinationIP"
   target => "icmpDest"
 }

}
output {
    csv {
    fields => "message"
    path => "/data/streamed-logs/%{[host]}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => "rubydebug"
    }
    elasticsearch {
         hosts => "address"

  }
}

**address having problem with geoIP:**
```

I can't get the geoIP for addresses which are in this format  e80::c0d3:531b:f0cf:f546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `IPV6` grok pattern instead of the `IPV4`

```
 grok {
     match => {
        "message" => "...%{IPV6:srcIP},%{IPV6:destIP},%{IPV6:icmpDetinationIP}..."
                              ^             ^              ^
                              |             |              |
                            here           here       and here
     }
 }
```

Comment: The part `%{NOTSPACE:tos}` is too greedy and captures too many fields. Besides, the sample log line doesn't match the grok pattern. You can try it out on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Do you want to update your question with your new grok?

Comment: <134>Mar 3 00:59:56 filterlog: 7,16777216,,1000000105,igb1,match,block,in,6,0x00,0xf12f0,255,UDP,17,524,fe80::1c7f:2ca0:6385:f414,ff02::fb,5353,5353,524 -new message format

Comment: I have edied the groke format also added a new message fromat

Comment: Actually, your grok only has a small error: `%{timestamp:timestamp}` should read `%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}`. Fix that and it will work.